# Import program to an Android NDK project having only the Android.mk file

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

Is it possible to import a program to an Android project (using NDK) having only the Android.mk file??

In that case, please could anyone tell me how I have to do this?

Comment: You mean, youdon't have the C++ source files?

Comment: Yes, I don't have the C++ source files

Comment: Unfortunalely, Android.mk only specifies _how_ to build something, not ***what*** to build. So you cannot reverse engineer Android.mk into a program.